# Watchdog is not monitoring the files at all

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am new to Python and trying to use the "watchdog" package to monitor changes to two files (file1.py and file2.py) in my project. I have looked through the documentation on using watchdog and searched through Stack Overflow for solutions, but I am still having trouble. Here is the structure of my files:

```
app
    - file_monitor.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
    - app.py
```

I want to run `file_monitor.py` and `app.py` separately, and have changes made to `file1.py` and `file2.py` be monitored. Even something as simple as `print("this is modified")` does not seem to be working.

Here is my current code:

```py
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import shutil

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("this is modified")
        # check if it's a file, not a directory, and if it's file1.py or file2.py
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(('file1.py', 'file2.py')):
            print(f'File modified: {event.src_path}')
            filename = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
            new_path = os.path.join('./backup', filename + '.backup' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
            shutil.copy2(event.src_path, new_path) # copy the file to the new path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    path="."
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False) # observe the specified directory
    observer.start()

    try:
        print("File watcher started. Watching directory './app'. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I also tried putting the whole path but it stays the same I only left on_modified with the print function and still nothing. What I could be doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: What is the working directory when the code runs? You can check with `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: i get this /mnt/d/projects/path/to/project/app which was exactly what i was using

Comment: You have `recursive=False`, so it's only monitoring changes to the directory itself, not the files contained in the directory. Adding, removing, or renaming files will trigger it, but not updating the file contents.

Comment: with true same thing nothing happens  observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True) it is like im not making any edits  this print(observer.is_alive()) returns true but not watching for changes on both files or anything inside the app folder

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue I dont know exactly how or why but I kept looking then I afound this https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/648
This code worked perfectly fine

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = "."
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = PollingObserver()
    print("Watching: ", path)
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    observer.is_alive()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

Comment: You replaced the native observer by PollingObserver, which is the last resource in case everything else fails. This is a good solution because you tried everything else, and clearly this was the only that worked. The original code looked OK though. At least on Linux watching the directory notifies you about modification to the files too, so adding "recursive=True" is not necessary there.